# Processing Gitlab variables with CLI tools

Tags: gitlab-ci

What I'm trying to do is getting user's first name to be displayed (`$GITLAB_USER_NAME` variable stores users' names as: `Lastname, Firstname`, so e.g. `Jones, Indiana`):

```yaml
deploy_to_server:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  script:
    - touch report.txt
    - printf "Hello $($GITLAB_USER_NAME | awk '{ print $2 }').\n" >> report.txt
    - cat report.txt
```

Any clue how to process the variable with `awk` so that it gives the desired output, `Hello Indiana`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, in this case `printf` could be replaced with `echo`:

```yaml
deploy_to_server:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  script:
    - touch report.txt
    - echo "Hello $GITLAB_USER_NAME" | awk '{ print $1 " " $3 ".\n\n" }' >> report.txt
    - cat report.txt
```

`awk` takes the first and the third column from the echoed string ([1]Hello [2]Jones, [3]Indiana), then I also added a space between words, and period followed by two newline characters.

In the end, the whole printout looks like this:

```
Hello Indiana.
```